# find $f^{(15)}(0)$ if $f = \frac{10x^2+12x+4}{(x+2) (x^2 +1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

$$f = \frac{10x^2+12x+4}{(x+2)(x^2 +1)}=\frac{4}{x+2}+\frac{6x}{x^2+1}=\frac{2}{1-\left(-\frac x 2 \right)}+\frac{6x}{1-(-x^2)}$$

So we end up with $$2 \sum_{n=0}^{15} \left(-\frac x 2 \right)^n + 6x \sum_{n=0}^{15} (-x^2)^n$$ but because we are looking for $f^{(15)}(0)$ we get the result of $2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a taylor polynomial for $f(x)$ i.e. $f(x) = \sum a_n x^n$ then
$f^{(n)}(0) = n! a_n$

Normally we think about this the other way around.  We want to find the coefficients and we say $a_n = \frac {f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$

$f(x) = 2\sum (-\frac 12)^n x^n + 6x\sum (-1)^n x^{2n}\\
a_{15} = 2 (-\frac 12)^{15} + 6 (-1)^7\\
 -2^{-14} - 6$

$f^{(15)}(0) = (-2^{-14} - 6)15!$

Comment: why $a_{15} = 2 (-\frac 12)^{15} + 6 (-1)^7$ is in 7th power and not 15? or it is not metter (odd number)?

Comment: We want to find the $x^{15}$ term.  In the summations you have provided, that will be when  $n=15$ in the first summation and $n=7$ in the second.

Answer (score 4):

It is more precise to write $$\begin{align*} f(x) &=  \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)^n + 6x(-x^2)^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2 (-1/2)^n x^n + \sum_{m=0}^\infty 6(-1)^m x^{2m+1} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k.
\end{align*}$$  Thus, $f^{(15)}(0)$ is $15!$ times the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in the series expansion.  Note this corresponds to the choices $n = 15$ and $m = 7$; i.e., $$f^{(15)}(0) = 15! \left( 2 (-1/2)^{15} + 6 (-1)^{7} \right).$$  This is because the coefficient of $x^{15}$ is found at different values of the indices of the series expansion of each term.

Answer (score 2):

$$
2 \sum_{n=0}^{15} \left(-\frac x 2 \right)^n + 6x \sum_{n=0}^{15} (-x^2)^n
$$

The $15$th-degree term of this sum is $\dfrac{f^{(15)}(0)}{15!} x^{15}.$

It is also $2\left( -\dfrac x 2 \right)^{15} + 6x(-x^2)^7.$

From that one can find $f^{(15)}(0).$

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \frac{4}{x+2} + \frac{3}{x+i} + \frac{3}{x-i}
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
f^{15}(x) = -(15!)(4(x+2)^{-16} + 3(x+i)^{-16} + 3(x-i)^{-16}
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
f^{15}(0) = -(2^{-14}+6)\cdot 15!
\end{align*}